# How to calculate the heatsink requirement for a diode?

Tags: diodes, bridge-rectifier

I think it's better explained with an example.

diode in question => https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/FERD30H100STS?qs=CXI0wBT1M2j9IrCh1JTRwA%3D%3D

forward voltage = 0.68V
forward current = 40A

in my case, the transformer secondary output is 24V 20A.

Does that mean I need to dissipate 0.68 x 20A = 7.3x watts of heat? (per diode)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That’s correct. Multiply that with the total Rth for your diode package, thermal interface and heatsink and you have your delta temperature to ambient. Have you considered a Schottky instead?

Comment: @winny I've been looking at the mouser catalog and all I can find are schottky in full-wave rectifier configuration. (unless of course I discard the other pin. example: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/SBR3060CTFP?qs=7r0W2zb%2F88y0dG0bciVHOQ%3D%3D

Comment: @mrjayviper That's not a full bridge rectifier, that's half of one. Two of those dual diodes could be used to make a full bridge rectifier however. But there are plenty of power Schottky diodes out there. I'd also question: you say the transformer's output is 20 A, but are you actually using it at 20 A? Many people new to this stuff have the misconception that rated current is always what's going to be output, but the actual current is determined by the load.

Comment: @Hearth the amp will be around 300W so it won't be using the full 20A. I guess I'm only overestimating it for safety?

Comment: **If** your diode dissipates 0.68V x 20A continuously, then yes, that's 7.3 watts of heat. And if it does that, you might consider a different circuit that doesn't waste so many watts of heat. E.g. a so-called "ideal diode bridge"

Answer (score 3):

> *In my case, the transformer secondary output is 24V 20A.*

When used in a bridge rectifier, the diode peak current will be a lot higher than 20 amps: -

[image]

Image above from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329443/current-through-the-smoothing-capacitor-in-bridge-rectifier).

I suggest you simulate the circuit to see what that is. Luckily, the duration of the current will be much less than half a cycle of AC so, the average power may possibly be smaller than your "continuous" estimate.

I strongly suggest simulation here.